# Duplicate `@ConfigurationProperties` in two different profile

Tags: java, spring-boot

Why can't I define two bean with the same `configurationProperties` prefix?  Code below throws the following error:

```
Duplicate `@ConfigurationProperties` definition for prefix 'config'
```

I know it is the same but for two different profile. Is there any other way I may
do it ?

```
@Profile("MyProfile")
@Bean(initMethod = "init", name = "MyConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public MyConfig config() {
    MyConfig config = new MyConfig();
    return config;
}

@Profile("!MyProfile")
@Bean(initMethod = "anotherInit", name = "MyConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public MyConfig myConfig() {
    MyConfig config = new MyConfig();
    return config;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-app: Compilation failure:
> Compilation failure:

> [ERROR] ...MyConfig.java:[21,22] Duplicate `@ConfigurationProperties` definition for prefix 'config'

Comment: I want to achieve different bean by profile with same config prefix for example same prefix database but for two different bean like hikariDataSource and AtomikosDataSource

Comment: which version of Spring boot is it ?

Comment: version 2.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: which IDE are you using ? I think it's the IDE which is creating compile issues. I found no issues in running the application.

Comment: no man it is really not problem of IDE . I updated question with compile error

Comment: I agree with SKumar, this should work perfectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in your comment, this compile time error is introduced by annotation processor - spring-boot-configuration-processor.

**How it decides whether duplicate configuration properties exists ?**

It decides on 2 things -

1. Property Prefix
2. Configuration class name / Return Type of the method

Notice that Spring profile name isn't part of finding duplicates. So, both configurations are similar. This is causing the compile time error.

**Solution**

Either you raise a bug with the spring api or do something that makes those 2 properties different. One way and I think the only way is to create a new configuration class that extends original one. This will ensure that they are not treated as duplicates.

```
class SomeOtherProfileConfig extends MyConfig {
}

@Profile("MyProfile")
@Bean(initMethod = "init", name = "MyConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public MyConfig config() {
    MyConfig config = new MyConfig();
    return config;
}

@Profile("!MyProfile")
@Bean(initMethod = "anotherInit", name = "MyConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public SomeOtherProfileConfig myConfig() {
    SomeOtherProfileConfig config = new SomeOtherProfileConfig();
    return config;
}
```

Comment: Is there another solution? In my case, I can't extend classes, because they are in different modules

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a single class for the `@ConfigurationProperties`, the properties will be picked from the active profile's properties file. Then, you can use the properties in different beans with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

Comment: hm I dont I can use EnableConfigurationProperties because as you see in my question there is also init method and I dont htink you can use init method with this annotation